# Scaling a border-radius 50% class in Chrome doesn't produce a perfect circle

Tags: css, transform

I have multiple circles produced by the following CSS:

```css
.map-circle {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: red;
}
```

For some reason when I scale that circle to a large number, the circle doesn't stay perfect in Chrome:

```css
.map-circle {
  transform: matrix(10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0);
}
```

```css
.map-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left:50px;
  top:50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: red;
  transform: matrix(10, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="map-circle"></div>
```

Seems to be a Chrome specific bug, atleast it's looking fine in Firefox + IE. Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: border-radius: 9999em; should do the trick... http://jsfiddle.net/m98y0wej/3/

Comment: sadly didn't do the trick :/ still seeing the same here. I actually just added a screenshot to my post with what I saw with your fiddle

Comment: Interesting fact: it seems to work if you use ems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is an issue with chrome. But when I use above code with even width and height (say 4px or 6px) it is working fine, but fails with odd widths like 5px.

Comment: that is so weird. with 5px it's acting weird, but when changed to 4px the circle is fine. This fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be because of how closely Chrome renders the circle. If you enlarge the circle (I tried 50 px), it showed a complete circle just fine. Apparently, with certain very small sizes, Chrome doesn't try as hard to render border-radiused corners.

If you want to fix this, an SVG might be a good option. Chrome shouldn't have any trouble rendering that one properly.

Comment: indeed SVG could be the way to go - just not an option in this case :/